# I can't find the project type Netduino

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, netduino

I've just got my netduino in the mail and installed the microframework and netduino sdk. In visual studio I have the C# branch Micro Framework but where is the project type "Netduino" What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2012 is not (yet) supported.

http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/5361-visual-studio-2012-and-netduino-plus/